# Replace a word with another one?

Tags: notepad++

I have two lists which countains about 200 lines per list :

List 1 :

```
University=123  
Faculty=456  
School=789  
Laboratory=101  
Academy=121
```

List 2 :

```
123=Student  
456=Teacher  
789=Professor  
101=Technician  
121=Engineer
```

The question is that I need a way to replace the word for ex: "University" with "123".. so the list 2 gonna be like this:

```
University=Student  
Faculty=Teacher  
School=Professor  
Laboratory=Technician  
Academy=Engineer
```

Can I do that with notepad++ or any other programs ?

Folks help me please !

Comment: would they be all in the same sequence ?

Comment: thanks for ur reply, nope they're not in the same sequence :/

Comment: were you able to find a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Vlookup using excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8Byv.png)
Check the image for one of the ways you can do it using excel. What I have done is,

I have split your two lists into 4 columns using the equals(=) as the de-limiter. Then using vlookup function in excel maatched the columns containing the numerical values and concatenated the two string columns with an equals(=) operator.

The formula for it is

```
 =CONCATENATE(A1,"=",VLOOKUP(B1,$D$1:$E$5,2,FALSE))
```

Assuming, the two lists have been split into four columns (A, B, D, E with B and D having the numerical values), the concatenate function concatenates all the strings that is passed to it within the parantheses; in this case the value in A, equals sign, and the value returned by the vlookup.

```
VLOOKUP(B1,$D$1:$E$5,2,FALSE)
```

What this formula does is, pick the value in B1, check for all matching values in the range D1 to E5, pick the second column in the range and check for exact matches(denoted by false).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have split the lists into 4 colmuns like you did in exel, but when I have put this code:  =CONCATENATE(A1,"=",VLOOKUP(B1,$D$1:$E$5,2,FALSE))   

http://i.imgur.com/QIaqZmD.jpg  

only the first line converted, how I can do it all in the same time ?

Comment: Drag the first column with the formula till the row that you want the values in as given [here](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/867-excel-apply-formula-to-entire-column-row.html)

Answer (score 1):

Press `CTRL H` and that will bring up the find and replace dialog box. There you can enter words like you normally do or even pass regex.

If you need to do the same thing for 200 lists then you may want to create a macro that does the repeating steps of the task for you.

Comment: Thank you sir for ur help, I think u didn't get what I want to do with those lists ?

Comment: aaah yes I misundrtstood. You need to.find the code in list 1 and use it to replace the word in list 2. Programming seems to be your only option, AFAIK. Shouldnt be a hard task though.

Comment: I have zero programming skills, how I can use AFAIK ?

Comment: AFAIK = As Far As I Know. It isnt a programming language

Comment: @Adarsh Yeah LOL.. I thought It's a programming language.

Answer (score 0):

```
Using Notepad++ it can be done very easily.
1. Copy the List1 in a new file.
2. Copy the List2 in another new file.
3. Select the Regex options in Find & Replace dialog box
4. Perform the following operations on List1 & List2 individually.
5. Finally Merge both the list.
---------------------------------------------------------
List1 : Find    --> =.*
        Replace --> =
-----------------------------
University=
Faculty=
School=
Laboratory=
Academy=
-----------------------------

List2 : Find    --> .*=
        Replace --> (Blank) 
-----------------------------
Student  
Teacher  
Professor  
Technician  
Engineer
-----------------------------
Final List3 : 
Select the complete List2, make  vertical select in List1 on the right hand side by selecting some blank horizontal area also.
Then just paste. :-)

University=     Student  
Faculty=        Teacher  
School=         Professor 
Laboratory=     Technician
Academy=        Engineer
```